# How to validate error and empty result in PHP

Tags: php

First, im new in PHP so please bear with me.

Im creating a web service for android, and this is my code :

```
if($size > 0)
{
    $resultArray = array();

    foreach($result as $child)
    {
        if($child)
        {
            //add to array
            $resultArray[] = array('result' => 'true', 
            'total' => $size,
            'id' => $child['id'], 
            'user_id' => $child['user_id'], 
            'name' => $child['name'], 
            'gender' => $child['gender'],
            'born_date' => $child['born_date'], 
            'born_hour' => $child['born_hour'],
            'hospital' => $child['hospital']);
        }
    }

    $this->response($resultArray, 200);
}
else
{
    $this->response(array('result' => 'false'), 404);
}
```

I use the size to validate whether the result is OK 200 (has some data) or error 404. However, there is a possibility that the result's size is 0 (no data) but the result is OK (code 200). How to tell the different?

I tried to use boolean variable instead of $size, but its not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what has to happen that the result is still valid even if size is `0`?

Comment: Debug first your `$size`. try to see how big it is.

Comment: This depends on how this response is handled

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER what i want is something like $this->response(array('result' => 'empty'), 200);

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel i knew its size, but i dont know how to handle the empty validation